# JSON data serialization in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am new to Xcode and Swift, and I am trying to serialize JSON data from a url using the code below and get the error

> 'NSJSONReadingOptions' is not convertible to 'NSJSONWritingOptions'

on the line

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)!
```

I cannot see my error, from online sources others use the same code and its works?

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(loginUrl!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
    }else {
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)!
        println(jsonResult)
    }
})

task.resume();
```

Comment: You're calling `dataWithJSONObject` which is used for serializing array/dictionary into JSON stored in a `NSData` object. But you want to call `JSONObjectWithData`, to deserialize JSON stored in `NSData` into an array/dictionary. The `NSJSONReadingOptions` is used with `JSONObjectWithData`. So, the problem isn't the `NSJSONReadingOptions`, but rather the fact that you called `dataWithJSONObject` instead of `JSONObjectWithData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs for `dataWithJSONObject`. The `options` parameter needs to be a value from the `NSJSONWritingOptions` enum, not the `NSJSONReadingOptions` enum.

But if your goal here is to convert an `NSData` object to an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, then the problem is that you are calling the wrong method. You want to use `JSONObjectWithData`, not `dataWithJSONObject`.

Comment: Thanks.. Solve my problem